# Best Resources for Facebook/Twitter Page Design

Tags: website-design, website-templates

I'm currently in the process of creating a few custom Facebook and Twitter backgrounds for some of my company properties and I wanted to know if there are any extensive galleries and tutorial/template sites focused heavily on this area of design.

So far I've checked a bunch of major design sites I follow, however most of their gallery posts are for CSS and traditional website design rather than social media.

Thanks very much in advance for any assistance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Check these link if someone can help you there..

Inspiration :

1. [30 twitter page design inspiration](http://www.web3mantra.com/2011/03/14/30-twitter-page-design-inspiration/)
2. [40 facebook fan page inspiration](http://inspirationfeed.com/2011/04/40-facebook-fan-page-designs-and-practices/)
3. [Facebook Page Design Galleries](http://www.thedesignwork.com/facebook-page-design-galleries/)
4. [Facebook layout](http://www.fbskins.com/facebook-layouts/?ref=61&gclid=CIHU0cKMo6oCFcl56wodpUUuVg)

---

Tutorials :

1. [Tutorial facebook landing page PSD included](http://www.standoutblogger.com/tutorials/tutorial-facebook-landing-page-template-psd-included/)
2. [Designing A Facebook Fan Page: Showcases, Tutorials, Resources](http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2010/07/07/designing-a-facebook-fan-page-showcases-tutorials-resources/)
3. [How to Create an Awesome Facebook Profile](http://sethsandler.com/headline/create-awesome-facebook-profile/)
4. [Facebook Page Development Tools and Tutorials](http://www.thedesignwork.com/facebook-page-development-tools-and-tutorials/)
5. [Cool Collection of Facebook Templates, Illustrations and Icons](http://www.photoshoplady.com/tutorial/cool-collection-of-facebook-templates-illustrations-and-icons/4323)

Hope this will help..

Comment: Thanks so much! Excellent sources and diversity. Very much appreciated.